# How to set table width and height in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have created a table like this:
dim table as Table = New Table(3)

SO now I have a Table with 3 columns.

But how do I set the width and height of the table?

Like table.width = 100px

Thank you

Comment: The [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.table(v=vs.110).aspx)-class has no constructor that takes an `Integer`. So what are you talking about? Apart from that you can assign the width in this way: `table.Width = New Unit(100, UnitType.Pixel)`

Answer (score 0):

A simple css can server the purpose .

```
   table
    {width : percentage or pixels }
```